# Path of two wheels at varying speeds

Tags: geometry

I have a follow up question to the answer given to [Calculating path of gradual turn given two wheel speeds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535351/calculating-path-of-gradual-turn-given-two-wheel-speeds)

The answer given is for a specific case where the two wheels are 2cm apart and the left wheel is rotating twice the speed of the right wheel.  The resulting path has a radius of 2 cm from the right wheel.  So what what is an equation to determine this radius for different speed ratios.

I see a pattern:

Given vl is the velocity of the left wheel and vr is the velocity of right wheel then:

- when vl = vr the radius is infinity so both wheels travel in parallel;
- when vl = 2 * vr the radius is relative to the right wheel and is equal to the axle length;
- when v1 = -v2 the radius is -1/2 the axle length such that the wheels rotate around the center of the axle.

So it appears that if a is the axle length then the radius r = a / (vl/vr-1) and is relative to the right wheel when vl > vr and relative to the left wheel when vl < vr.  I wonder if this is correct and again how to properly come to this or the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume a circular trajectory such that the radius is $r_l$ on the left and $r_r$ on the right (and $d:=r_r-r_l$ is the axle length).

The ratio of the radii is the ratio of the angular speeds of the wheels and at the same time the ratio of the linear speeds,

$$\frac{r_r}{r_l}=1+\frac d{r_l}=\frac{\omega_r}{\omega_l}=\frac{v_r}{v_l}.$$

From this you draw

$$r_l=\frac{v_l}{v_r-v_l}d, \\r_r=\frac{v_r}{v_r-v_l}d.$$

This also works with negative values.